# Can't get certain elements from a variable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am scraping thise site https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/berlin/berlin/haus-kaufen?enteredFrom=one_step_search, and from this variable:

```
square_meter_str = text.replace('m²', '').replace(',', '').strip()
```

I get these values:

> 232
> 1.264
> 8426
> 990
> 175
> 801
> 140
> 599
> 117
> 581
> 72
> 160
> 110
> 266
> 145
> 519
> 290
> 917
> 151
> 520
> 116
> 0
> 172
> 206
> 46
> 1.024
> 479
> 1.040
> 1.18904
> 424
> 29148
> 1.007
> 135
> 599
> 156
> 444

So this variable should scrape square meters of inside the house, but it also scrapes the square meters of outside the house. I would like to get only square meters of the inside the house, in this case 232, 8426, 175, 140, and so on (so every odd value). How can I achieve this, or can I somehow change the code so it only scrapes the square meters of the inside of the house?

P.S. Here is the full code of the function where that variable is:

```
def extract_information(soup):
    information = soup.find_all('dd', class_='font-highlight font-tabular')
    links = [info.find_previous('div', class_='grid-item').find('a')['href'] for info in information]

    for link, info in zip(links, information):
        house_link = f"https://www.immobilienscout24.de{link}"

        # Extract and print only the prices and square meters
        text = info.getText().strip()
        try:
            if '€' in text:
                # Remove euro sign and convert to int
                price = int(text.replace('€', '').replace('.', '').replace(',', '').strip())
            elif 'm²' in text:
                # Remove square meter sign and convert to int
                square_meter_str = text.replace('m²', '').replace(',', '').strip()
                print(square_meter_str)

                # Handle cases where dot is used as a thousand separator
                if '.' in square_meter_str and square_meter_str.count('.') == 1:
                    # If there is only one dot, consider it as a thousand separator
                    square_meter_str = square_meter_str.replace('.', '')
                elif '.' in square_meter_str and square_meter_str.count('.') > 1:
                    # If there are multiple dots, keep only the last one as the decimal point
                    square_meter_str = square_meter_str.rsplit('.', 1)[0] + square_meter_str.rsplit('.', 1)[1].replace('.', '')

                # Convert to float, handle the case when it's zero
                square_meter = float(square_meter_str) if square_meter_str else 0.0

                # Check if square_meter is non-zero before division
                if square_meter != 0:
                    price_per_square_meter = price / square_meter

                    # Check if price_per_square_meter is within the specified range
                    if 2000 <= price_per_square_meter <= 3000:
                        # Append data to the list for saving to Excel
                        house_data['House link'].append(house_link)
                        house_data['Price per square meter [€]'].append(price_per_square_meter)
        except:
            print("Price or the living space information is missing.")

    return house_data
```

I tried saving it in a list and than looping the list to get every second value but I didn't work. I even tried asking ChatGPT but it didn't help.

Comment: `square_meter_str.split()[::2]`

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested your function however to extract the elements you want from the result you could split the string on the spaces and then step over the odd elements.

```
square_meters = square_meter_str.split(" ")[::2]
```

The split method makes a list of strings from the original string. The slicing with a step of 2 returns all the odd elements.

A small note: in your comment you mention convert to int. To do this you would still have to convert the outcome. For example,

```
square_meters = list(map(int,square_meter_str.split(" ")[::2]))
```

In the specific result you provided you will get an error as not all values can be converted to an integer.

```
list(map(int,[m for m in square_meter_str.split(" ") if not "." in m]))
```

or

```
list(map(int,[m for m in square_meter_str.split(" ")[::2] if not "." in m]))
```

will give you a list of integers.

**EDIT**

After looking at the page in question and understanding that the output is a string instead of a list. A solution could be `round(float(text.replace('m²', '').replace(',', '.').split("- ")[0]))`

Comment: The comment is not good. It converts it to float in this line: ```square_meter = float(square_meter_str) if square_meter_str else 0.0```. I have done the following:  ```square_meter_str = text.replace('m²', '').replace(',', '').strip().split(" ")[::2] ``` but it still gives me the same results. The variable square_meter_str is not a list. Is that a problem?

Comment: @user23588862, After taking a look on the page you are scrapping I think you are taking this element, correct? `<dd class="font-highlight font-tabular">246,73 m²</dd>`. This would be a string. However, I am unclear by what you mean with getting every odd value.

Comment: I am scraping this site: https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/berlin/berlin/haus-kaufen?enteredFrom=one_step_search    I want to scrape only the square meters of the house, but this code as you can see in the post, scrapes the square meters of the house and square meteres that are around the house. Can I adjust the code so that it only scrapes the square meters of the house or can I someone extract them (they are the every odd value as shown in original post)?

Comment: After looking at the site I think you could single out the elements that contain the `Wohnfläche` or `<dt class="font-tabular onlyLarge font-xs attribute-label">Wohnfläche</dt>`. This will give you the square meters you want.

Comment: Will try that tonight and get back to you.

Comment: How would I extract that information?

Comment: That's a good question. I haven't done much web scraping yet. But reading through the tutorials from BeautifulSoup and looking at the page and testing it. This should work: `categories = [info.find_next_siblings("dt") for info in information]`. Add this after the row `information = soup...` and include it in the loop. This way you can use it as a criterion to filter on.

Comment: @NewUser, did you get the information from the site like you wanted?

Comment: Yes I did. I have written the code below.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your function would look like if you would also scrape and use attributes from the listings:

```
def extract_information(soup):
    information = soup.find_all('dd', class_='font-highlight font-tabular')
    categories = [info.find_next_siblings("dt", class_="font-tabular onlyLarge font-xs attribute-label") for info in information]
    links = [info.find_previous('div', class_='grid-item').find('a')['href'] for info in information]

    for link, info, cat in zip(links, information, categories):
        house_link = f"https://www.immobilienscout24.de{link}"
        # Extract and print only the prices and square meters
        text = info.getText().strip()
        cat_text = cat[0].getText().strip()

        try:
            if '€' in text:
                # Remove euro sign and convert to int
                price = int(text.replace('€', '').replace('.', '').replace(',', '').strip())
            elif 'm²' in text and cat_text == "Wohnfläche":
                # Remove square meter sign and convert to int
                square_meter_str = text.replace('m²', '').replace(',', '').strip()
                print(square_meter_str)

                # Handle cases where dot is used as a thousand separator
                if '.' in square_meter_str and square_meter_str.count('.') == 1:
                    # If there is only one dot, consider it as a thousand separator
                    square_meter_str = square_meter_str.replace('.', '')
                elif '.' in square_meter_str and square_meter_str.count('.') > 1:
                    # If there are multiple dots, keep only the last one as the decimal point
                    square_meter_str = square_meter_str.rsplit('.', 1)[0] + square_meter_str.rsplit('.', 1)[1].replace('.', '')

                # Convert to float, handle the case when it's zero
                square_meter = float(square_meter_str) if square_meter_str else 0.0

                # Check if square_meter is non-zero before division
                if square_meter != 0:
                    price_per_square_meter = price / square_meter

                    # Check if price_per_square_meter is within the specified range
                    if 2000 <= price_per_square_meter <= 3000:
                        # Append data to the list for saving to Excel
                        house_data['House link'].append(house_link)
                        house_data['Price per square meter [€]'].append(price_per_square_meter)
        except:
            print("Price or the living space information is missing.")
     return house_data
```

Comment: @user23588862, here is what I think is this answer you're looking for. With this approach there would be no need for any string parsing or list slicing. If this answered your question would you be inclined to mark it as accepted.

Comment: I have found a solution (see the answer bellow yours). I will try your code out and let you know if it works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I have found a solution. I have changed this part:

```
information = soup.find_all('dd', class_='font-highlight font-tabular')
    links = [info.find_previous('div', class_='grid-item').find('a')['href'] for info in information]

    for link, info in zip(links, information):
        house_link = f"https://www.immobilienscout24.de{link}"

        # Extract and print only the prices and square meters
        text = info.getText().strip()
```

to this part:

```
containers = soup.find_all('div', class_='grid grid-flex grid-align-center grid-justify-space-between')

    # Iterate over containers
    for container in containers:
        # Find all dd elements within the container
        informations = container.find_all('dd')

        # Extract links from a elements within the container
        links = container.find_all('a')
        links_list = [f"https://www.immobilienscout24.de{link.get('href')}" for link in links]

        # Extract text from dd elements
        variable = [information.getText() for information in informations]
```

Here is the code for the entire function:

```
def extract_information_house(soup):
    # Find all containers
    containers = soup.find_all('div', class_='grid grid-flex grid-align-center grid-justify-space-between')

    # Iterate over containers
    for container in containers:
        # Find all dd elements within the container
        informations = container.find_all('dd')

        # Extract links from a elements within the container
        links = container.find_all('a')
        links_list = [f"https://www.immobilienscout24.de{link.get('href')}" for link in links]

        # Extract text from dd elements
        variable = [information.getText() for information in informations]

        # Extract price and square meter information from the correct positions
        for i in range(0, len(variable), 2):
            # Check if there are enough elements in the variable list
            if i + 1 < len(variable):
                price_text = variable[i]
                square_meter_text = variable[i + 1]
                print(f"0. {square_meter_text}")
                # Check if both price and square meter information are present
                if price_text and square_meter_text:
                    try:
                        # Remove euro sign and convert price to int
                        price = int(price_text.replace('€', '').replace('.', '').replace(',', '').strip())

                        # Remove square meter sign and convert to float
                        square_meter_str = square_meter_text.replace('m²', '').strip()
    
                        # Remove all commas
                        square_meter_str = square_meter_str.replace(',', '.')
                    
                        # Replace the first dot with an empty string to prevent decimal issues
                        if square_meter_str.count('.') == 2:
                            square_meter_str = square_meter_str.replace('.', '', 1)
                

                        # Check if there are three digits after the dot and remove the dot if true
                        if '.' in square_meter_str and len(square_meter_str.split('.')[1]) == 3:
                            square_meter_str = square_meter_str.replace('.', '', 1)

                        # Convert square meter to float
                        square_meter = float(square_meter_str) if square_meter_str else 0.0
                        
                        # Check if square_meter is non-zero before division
                        if square_meter != 0:
                            price_per_square_meter = round(price / square_meter, 2)
            
                            # Check if price_per_square_meter is within the specified range
                            if 2000 <= price_per_square_meter <= 3000:
                                # Append data to the list for saving to Excel
                                house_data['House link'].extend(links_list)
                                house_data['Price per square meter [€]'].append(price_per_square_meter)
                    except (ValueError, IndexError):
                        #print("Price or the living space information is missing or invalid.")
                        pass

    return house_data
```